# What is the easiest way to setup a webserver on Mac?

Tags: backup, web-server, drupal, mamp, easy-install

I am looking for the easiest way to run a webserver with Drupal on Mac. MAMP PRO is a nice solution but some people say that it is for the local usage only. Can it be used as a full-scale webserver?

What would you recommend for an easy auto-backup to another machine via ssh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course MAMP can be used for a full scale webserver, thats what half of the Internet runs ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a tad bit confusing. Are you looking to set up a local development environment or a "full-scale" hosting environment? MAMP is comprised of the components common to many web-application/hosting environments. If you're looking for a local installation on which to develop, MAMP should work just fine for you. If you're looking to serve something publicly, I'd look to a hosting provider that offers some flavor of LAMP.

Comment: I was not very clear -- I want to host a global web site on my Mac. And I want it to be set up as easy as possible, allowing my not very experienced colleagues to manage it without a brain damage. According to Aleksandar, MAMP [PRO] can work for me. The only thing left is auto-backup to another Mac or/and Time Capsule. And restore/rollback... and remote management...